# Python copy function beahvior

Tags: python, dictionary, copy

I'm trying to do a report tool based on python dict but when I print the result i'm facing on reference issue.

```
yn = {"success":{}, "error":{}}
status = {"creation":yn.copy(), "update":yn.copy().copy()}
status['creation']['success']['ali'] = "Ok"
print (status)
```

And I get:

```
{'update': {'success': {'ali': 'Ok'}, 'error': {}}, 'creation': {'success': {'ali': 'Ok'}, 'error': {}}}
```

I don't understand why `yn.copy().copy()` not acting like I want.

Comment: What exactly do you expect to happen?

Comment: @JonClements, i expected copy returns copied dict from yn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`yn.copy()` returns a new dictionary, a **shallow** copy of `yn`. Calling `.copy()` on that again will just return *another* shallow copy.

Use `copy.deepcopy()` instead, if you wanted the nested dictionaries to be copied too:

```
import copy

status = {"creation": copy.deepcopy(yn), "update": copy.deepcopy(yn)}
```

or better still, use a factory function to produce the `yn` dictionary:

```
make_yn = lambda: {"success":{}, "error":{}}
status = {"creation": make_yn(), "update": make_yn()}
```

Comment: Very nice the use of lambda :) !